# C# - Unable to add item to listview from method invoked from class

Tags: c#, class, listview, methods, void

Im having a strange problem with my programme, whenever I call a method from another class, it doesnt work as expected. Basically, what I am trying to do is add an item to a listview, and the code is in a method, and I am trying to invoke that method from another class. Here is my code:

```
public class Main1
 {
   public void addItemToLV(string text)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(text);    
    }
 }

public class MainForm
{
   Main1 m1 = new Main1();
   m1.addItemToLV("test");
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does it work when you try to call it from the class itself?

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. You cannot have statements inside a class (outside of a function). See MainForm definition for what I'm talking about. Would you please repost with more complete code?

Comment: I mean have you tried to call the method from Main1 ?

Comment: please post a code example that compiles and makes the problem reproducible

Comment: are you using WinForms? WPF? ...

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the controls on a form are declared as protected properties within the designer.cs file rather than public properties, so those controls will normally not be accessible to code outside of the form on which they are declared.  This is intentional, as it encourages good object-oriented programming habits.

Rather than modifying a control directly from code that exists outside the form, a better practice is to declare public methods and properties within your form that can be called from outside code to manipulate the protected controls:

```
public class Main1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      var mainForm = new MainForm();
      mainForm.AddItemToListView("test");
    }
}

public class MainForm
{
    public void AddItemToListView(string text)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(text);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code sample is not enough but I am trying to guess the reason behind the issue and I think it is one of the following: 
1.You are initialising your `listView1` in the load event of `Main1`, and you are trying to show the form after calling the method. In that case you should call the method after showing the `Main1` form.
2. Or simply you are trying to call the method on a different instance than the one displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass the ListView as an argument in the constructor and make the function return this ListView to your MainWindow.

```
public class Main1
    {
        private readonly ListView _lv;
        public Main1(ListView listview)
        {
            _lv = listview;
        }
        public ListView addItemToLV(string text)
        {
            _lv.Items.Add(text);

            return _lv;
        }
    }
```